# How to handle cancelled webdav PUT operations

Tags: webdav

As I am writing my own WebDAV server - based on SabreDAV (php) - I came along with the problem, that most clients (all but Windows Explorer) do not send a `DELETE` request when the user has cancelled a file upload (`PUT` request).

I could not find any hint for that (eg in the RFCs) whether the client has to do so or how the server could figure out that not all file contents have been streamed/sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out that most clients send `Content-Length` header with the stream. So I will be able to use that information to undo file creation.

Comment: RFC 7230 explains how the message body length is detected (even in absence of Content-Length).